# Swift generics error when using more than one generic

Tags: swift, generics, operator-overloading, protocols

I'm trying to define an helper method to set AutoLayout constraints to UIViews. Ideally, it should be a function `anchor` defined in the UIView class that operates in this way:

```swift
let A = UIView()
let B = UIView()
B.anchor(left: A.rightAnchor + 24, top: A.bottomAnchor, width: A.widthAnchor + 100, height: 200)
```

where `A.rightAnchor + 24` means that the leftAnchor of the second view should be constrained to the rightAnchor of the first view with a constant of 24.

Here's what I tried to do to achieve this behavior:

to simplify let's assume `anchor(_ left:)` has only one parameter that can either be:

- an `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor`
- an `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` + `CGFloat`

#### Protocol that all those input Types have to implement

```
protocol LayoutProtocol {
    // LayoutType can be NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor or NSLayoutDimension
    associatedtype LayoutType

    var anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<LayoutType> { get }
    var constant: CGFloat { get }
}
```

Let now `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` and `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` conform to that protocol:

```
extension NSLayoutXAxisAnchor: LayoutProtocol {
    typealias LayoutType = NSLayoutXAxisAnchor

    var anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor> { return self }
    var constant: CGFloat { return 0 }
}

extension NSLayoutYAxisAnchor: LayoutProtocol {
    typealias LayoutType = NSLayoutYAxisAnchor

    var anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor> { return self }
    var constant: CGFloat { return 0 }
}
```

#### Sum operator between `NSLayoutAnchor<AnchorType>` and `CGFloat`

Let's define a struct conforming with that protocol:

```
struct LayoutOperation<T>: LayoutProtocol {
    typealias LayoutType = T

    var anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<T>
    var constant: CGFloat
}
```

Now, the sum operator can return that struct:

```
func +<T>(left: NSLayoutAnchor<T>, right: CGFloat) -> LayoutOperation<T> {
    return LayoutOperation<T>(anchor: left, constant: right)
}
```

#### Anchor function with one parameter only

Finally, we can extend `UIView` class:

```
extension UIView {

    func anchor<T: LayoutProtocol>(_ left: T? = nil) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        if let left = left {
            constraints.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.anchor as! NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>, constant: left.constant))
        }

        constraints.forEach { $0.isActive = true }
    }

}
```

It works and I can pass an `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` alone or with an `Int` or a `Double` summed to its right.

---

Let's now focus on generalizing the structures and on adding other parameters to `anchor()`.

- `LayoutProtocol` is general
- `LayoutOperation<T>` is also general
- The sum operator can handle every `NSLayoutAnchor` specialization too

There shouldn't be problems, so:

```
extension UIView {

    func anchor<T: LayoutProtocol, U: LayoutProtocol>(left: T? = nil, top: U? = nil) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        if let left = left {
            constraints.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.anchor as! NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>, constant: left.constant))
        }
        if let top = top {
            constraints.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top.anchor as! NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>, constant: top.constant))
        }

        constraints.forEach { $0.isActive = true }
    }

}
```

`T` and `U` are different generics since horizontal and vertical anchors have different specialized types (in total 3 generic types will be sufficient to handle every kind of layout anchor).

Test cases:

```
B.anchor(left: A.rightAnchor + 24, top: A.bottomAnchor)
B.anchor(left: A.rightAnchor + 24, top: A.bottomAnchor + 12)
B.anchor(left: A.rightAnchor, top: A.bottomAnchor)
B.anchor(left: A.leftAnchor, top: A.topAnchor + 120.5)
```

All working fine as expected.

But if I pass only one parameter, either left or top:

```
B.anchor(left: A.rightAnchor + 24)
B.anchor(top: A.bottomAnchor)
```

Swift doesn't compile anymore and the following error appears

> `Cannot convert call result type 'LayoutOperation<_>' to expected type '_?'`

I also tried to add `where` to specify the associated type, with no luck:

```
extension UIView {

    func anchor<T: LayoutProtocol, U: LayoutProtocol>(left: T? = nil, top: U? = nil)
      where T.LayoutType == NSLayoutXAxisAnchor,
            U.LayoutType == NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        if let left = left {
            constraints.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left.anchor, constant: left.constant))
        }
        if let top = top {
            constraints.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top.anchor, constant: top.constant))
        }

        constraints.forEach { $0.isActive = true }
    }

}
```

Still the same error.

Any suggestion on how to solve this? I'm relatively new to Swift, so this certainly can be the worst way to handle a (cool) feature like this. Beside that, thanks in advance!

Comment: Because compiler does not know the type of the other generic value ‘T’ or ‘U’ so maybe you should write another function for the single argument and remove the default value

Comment: @zombie, in the final function I will have: left, top, bottom, right, centerX, centerY, width and height. Am I supposed to add 8! functions to handle all of the 8 parameters?

Comment: Or try to remove the default value and pass the value that you want in the call

Comment: `B.anchor(left: A.leftAnchor, top: nil)` produces the same compiling error. Maybe the casting is the only thing that generates that error. I'll try different unwrapping methods.